# Cómo saber si un número está en dos listas diferentes en Python

Tags: python

Tengo una función que debería retornar True si hay por lo menos un número igual en las dos listas, ejemplo:

```
def numeroEnListas():
    lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    lista2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
    return True
```

Retorna True porque el 4 está en las dos listas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando `sets`. Si el set resultante está vacio, es decir, ambas listas no tienen valores en común, la función retornará `False`.

```
def numeroEnListas():
    lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    lista2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]

    #creo un set con los valores que ambas listas tienen en comun.
    #y lo convierto en booleano.
    return bool(set(lista1) & set(lista2))

print(numeroEnListas())
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta función recorre los elementos de la primera lista y revisa que si están en la segunda lista, produciendo una lista de `True` y `False`. Luego usamos la función `any(iterable)`, que retorna `True` si alguno de los elementos es `True`.

Aplicando compresión de listas

```
def numeroEnListas(lista1, lista2):
    return any(x in lista2 for x in lista1)
```

**Demo**

```
lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lista2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
lista3 = [8, 9, 10, 11]

print(numeroEnListas(lista1, lista2))
print(numeroEnListas(lista1, lista3))
```

produce

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta función debe ser una de las formas más veloces de hacerlo. Todos los números repetidos se añadirán al array repetido y si este tiene algún valor la función devolverá True.

```
def numeroEnListas():
    lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    lista2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
    repetido = [n for n in lista1 if n in lista2]
    if repetido:
        return True
```

Con esto puedes comprobar cual es el más veloz:

```
from timeit import timeit

def numeroEnListas1():
    lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    lista2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
    return bool(set(lista1) & set(lista2))

def numeroEnListas2():
    lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    lista2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
    repetido = [n for n in lista1 if n in lista2]
    if repetido:
        return True

def numeroEnListas3():
    lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    lista2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
    return any(x in lista2 for x in lista1)

# Control del tiempo
f1 = timeit(stmt=numeroEnListas1, number=1000000)
f2 = timeit(stmt=numeroEnListas2, number=1000000)
f3 = timeit(stmt=numeroEnListas3, number=1000000)
print(f'Método uno: {f1}\nMétodo dos: {f2}\nMétodo tres: {f3}')
```

Resultado:

```
Método uno: 0.7705103000000001
Método dos: 0.8890395999999999
Método tres: 1.1741319
```